# Auto-adjusting size for Tkinter frame

Tags: python, menu, tkinter

I'm working on a gui and I'd like to know how to adjust the size of the menus of a frame in order to have them take all the  horizontal space of the frame.

The problem has changed : now the menu buttons are ok when the window is in normal size but when I resize it the menu buttons drop in the middle of the window. How can I make them stick to the top of the frame ?

rgds,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question lacks enough detail to give you a good answer. Are you creating a menubar by putting menu buttons in a frame? If so, that's the wrong way to do it. Create a menu widget and assign it to the menu property of the main window and you'll end up with standard menus that behave normally.

Here's a simple example:

```
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()
menubar = Tkinter.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menubar)

fileMenu = Tkinter.Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
editMenu = Tkinter.Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)

menubar.add_cascade(label="File",underline=0, menu=fileMenu)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit",underline=0, menu=editMenu)

fileMenu.add_command(label="Open...", underline=0)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Save", underline=0)
fileMenu.add_separator()
fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=1)

editMenu.add_command(label="Cut", underline=2)
editMenu.add_command(label="Copy", underline=0)
editMenu.add_command(label="Paste", underline=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips. My main window being a frame does it have a menu property ?

Comment: @Bruno: "menu" is an attribute of toplevel windows. Every Tkinter app has at least (and usually only) one. This is commonly called "root". I'll add an example to my answer to hopefully clarify.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your approach and it works great. 
There is only a minor problem : when i resize the window the menus stay in the left of the menu bar, is it possible to have them to take all the horizontal space (curiosity) ?

Comment: @Bruno: no, it is not possible, and you don't want to do that. Your menu should be consistent with standard menu behavior. Your users will thank you. 

If you _really_ need the behavior you describe your only choice is to use frames and menubuttons. I don't recommend that approach if you're trying to create a GUI that people will want to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll follow your recommendation !